# Why does my background image seem to be stretched with bgsize "contain"?

Tags: css

> `contain`
>
> Scales the image as large as possible **without cropping or stretching** the image.

I was trying to replicate an css effect I saw on a social website. It uses 3 background images to form a "post background" (Users have to pay for it). Here's the ideal effect https://jsfiddle.net/Yun93/7hmgnjod/2/

**Question:**

But when I was playing around with these 3 images , I didn't understand that why the 2nd image seem to get stretched with `background-size: contain` whlie the other 2 does not. **They all have same width**! They all should behave the same! Why?

And changing all `background-size: contain` to `background-size: cover` , the 2nd image also behaves differently. Aagin, why?

---

Code: the 2nd image seem to get stretched with `background-size: contain`

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
} 

.container {
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg1 {
background-image: url('https://imgur.com/bTn61bZ.png');
background-size:contain;
/* background-size:cover; */
height: 35px;
}

.bg2 {
background-image: url('https://imgur.com/SjxzI9V.png');
background-size:contain;
/* background-size:cover; */

}


.bg3 {
background-image: url('https://imgur.com/oNTSRHW.png');
background-size:contain;
/* background-size:cover; */
height: 68px;
}

.bg1, .bg2, .bg3 {
width: 100%;
}

.content {
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg2">
        <div class="content">
            People have their post here.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please use `background-size:auto;` instead of  `background-size:contain;` .

Comment: In this case. Please make sure your container div width should be the same as your background image size. currently, your background image width is 550px and your container div width is 700px.

Comment: @PrakashRajotiya You are not answering the question :).  And I delibrately makes the containing div wider than the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `background-size: contain` your image is not stretched, but it scales to fill available space without losing its width/height ratio. In your case, your second image has a very little height (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfm90.png) so it can take the whole width of its container. In the fiddle the width of the container is 550px and it is 700 px in your code.

Comment: Ah, thanks I get the point. I didin't know that the height also affects the effect of `background-size: contain`. After setting all 3 divs to the same height, they matches.

Comment: `background-repeat` has nothing to do with this. I know the default `repeat` effect and it's used for the 2nd image to get the expected effect.

Comment: Also I was confused with the word "scale" and "stretch". Now I know that the former means enlarge or shrink without losing original ratio while the latter means the ratio would be broken. Btw, I suggest you removing the last paragraph then I can accept the answer. Thank you again ;)

Comment: @Rick I have removed the last paragraph